# How to sort lines based on a sub string in the line

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, ash

I have the following output:

```
aaa=12
bbb=124
cccc=1
dddd=15
```

I want to sort the above lines based on the value.s so the output should look like this:

```
$ cat file | awk_or_sed_or_any_command
cccc=1
aaa=12
dddd=15
bbb=124
```

**UPDATE**

I tried the following commands:

```
$ cat file | awk -F '=' '{print $2"="$1}' | sort |  awk -F '=' '{print $2"="$1}'
```

But it's too long.

Are there another suggestion better than the above one?

Note: my linux use sort from busybox that support only the following options:

```
$ sort --help
BusyBox v1.19.4 (2014-04-04 18:50:39 CEST) multi-call binary.

Usage: sort [-nru] [FILE]...

Sort lines of text

        -n      Sort numbers
        -r      Reverse sort order
        -u      Suppress duplicate lines
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the following command

```
sort -n -t = -k 2 your_file
```

gives me

```
alex@rhyme ~ $ ash
$ cat <<EOF | sort -n -t = -k 2
> aaa=12
> bbb=124
> cccc=1
> dddd=15
> EOF 
cccc=1
aaa=12
dddd=15
bbb=124
$ which sort
/usr/bin/sort
$ LANG=C sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.21
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.
```

Check the [sort manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort) for other `sort` options

Comment: the output is not sorted in the right way. Could you please share the output of your command. here after what I get: `aaa=12
bbb=124
cccc=1
dddd=15
`

Comment: It worked for bash but not for ash. I tagged my question with ash

Comment: Good one, would be good to indicate that `-n` is to sort numerically, `-k X` to sort on column `X` and `-t =` sets the field separator.

Comment: @fedorqui thank you! Probably I should also mention [the whole sort man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort)

Comment: @MOHAMED This works alright using `GNU sort` and `busybox sort`. The shell does not matter, your `sort` implementation does.

Comment: It's probably `-k 2` that's throwing your `sort` off as that's only supported on some modern `sort`s. Try `sort -n -t = +1 -2` - that should work with any sort.

Comment: @EdMorton My sort (busy box is too limited) there is only the following options `-n      Sort numbers
        -r      Reverse sort order
        -u      Suppress duplicate lines`

Comment: I updated my question. Iadded the help of my sort (from busybox)

Comment: OK, you've GOT to get yourself a new platform to work on, or at least a new toolset. There's only so much you can accomplish with rocks and pointy sticks.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/=\(.*\)$/=000000\1_\1/;s/=0*\([0-9]\{7\}\)_/=\1_/' YourFile | sort | sed -e 's/=[0-9]_/=/'
```

prepare for a basic `sort` not numeric nor taking column than put back in original form